# Trouble with syntax using Python and Pandas to imitate an SQL query in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

I am using:

- Python3
- Pandas
- Sqllite3 on my local (will be Postgresql on production, although
  this should not matter for this purpose)

I have a project where I am attempting to remove some joins, counts, groups and other aggregate functions from queries - they all need to be moved to code.

I am new to Python and have skimmed the Pandas manual and other resources on StackOverflow.

I am attempting to recreate the following query:

```
SELECT D.ID, D.Name, COUNT(W.ID)
FROM Departments D
LEFT JOIN Widgets W ON D.ID=W.department
GROUP BY D.ID, D.Name
HAVING COUNT(W.ID)>0
```

On the Python side - just using two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM departments
SELECT * FROM widgets
```

I could be wrong, but I believe this is what needs to happen:

- Import the python module and create a connection
- Import Pandas    (from what i understand this is an arguably
  efficient tool for this    type of work)
- Assign my queries to a variable
- Have Pandas read    the queries
- (Merge?) the query results to construct a dataframe
- Perform    count and aggregation using methods on the dataframe

I am struggling with the syntax and am having trouble determining if I am even going about this the right way.  Both tables passed into the queries have multiple columns above and beyond what I am working with, which could be contributing to the difficulty.

The result should have the Department ID, Department Name and a count of widgets belonging to the department.  Here is the python code I have been experimenting with:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
...  #functions and connection info removed
with conn:
  sql1="SELECT * FROM departments"
  sql2="SELECT * FROM widgets"
  #print("Read Queries Into Dataframes")
  df = pd.read_sql(sql1, conn)
  lf = pd.read_sql(sql2, conn)
  #print("Connected and read - print the dataframe")
  merged_df=pd.merge(df, lf, left_on='id', right_on='department', how='inner') #.groupby(['id'])
  #result=merged_df.groupby(['id'])
  #result = pd.merge(df, lf, on='key')
  #print(result)
```

Notes:

- It appears to (mostly) work until I introduce the group by It appears
- I am getting a key error in ID - perhaps this is a syntax error or I 
  do not have something aliased properly
- Changing the join type (how)    from Left to Inner yields some NAN
  results

Comment: Left join will give you NaN results for every Department without any widget.
I would add count() to the groupby -> `merged_df.groupby(['id']).count()`

Comment: You can also group by id and name -> `merged_df.groupby(['id', 'name']).count()`

Comment: Thank you both - very useful information.  I was able to handle this with something along the lines of:  pd.merge(df_departments[["id", "dname"]], df_widgets[["department", "widgetid", "purchased","Type"]], how='inner', left_on='id', right_on='department'